# How can I prevent 'Error messages' to be shown to anonymous users?

Tags: debugging, users

Like any Drupal site, my site also shows red notifications from time to time...

The problem is that when these notifications are **error messages**, they appear at the bottom of the site in a new "Pseudo-reigion"... I use the term "Pseudo-region" because they establish a new "Region" under the site.

It's not really a region but rather a white area with an H1 and some text under it. It is displayed with the word "*Error*" (as a title, using a `<h1>` HTML tag), and the text below it is "*The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.*". This is how it looks like in my site:

[image]

So my single aim is to not display these error messages (and this whole "Pseudo region" actually), at least for anonymous users, since it's uglyfies my site.

I've tried to use the following CSS syntax but with no success:

```
body.not-logged-in div.messages.error {display: none !important;}
```

This "error" pseudo-region is extremely problematic since it appears even in cases when I hide the notifications themselves via the "[Disable messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages)" module.

I'm sure this error is native to Drupal but I've already tried everything I know to remove it, so any help is appreciated.

### An important note

**It's a long story why**, but disabling the errors through `/admin/config/development/logging` doesn't help in this case. I'm looking for a solution which is either CSS, a Javascript (not jQuery) tweaking of the css by the text itself, or, some change in the Drupal PHP code that will prevent to program of printing this error.

Comment: Go to /admin/config/development/logging What is "Error Messages to Display" set to?

Comment: As you're asking for a "pure CSS solution" this is off topic here. Questions about CSS can be asked on Stack Overflow, though. If you change your mind and decide a Drupal-related solution will work, just edit the question and flag for re-opening

Comment: This message is not generated by Drupal. This is generated by your webserver/php and should be logged as a 500 error in your PHP or Web Server logs which you need to look at and fix. Hiding the error is like covering the white elephant in the room with a cloth and pretending like it's not there.

Comment: It caused when a certain module works. But anyway, how can you prove it relates to the PHP?

Comment: You've proven it relates to PHP yourself @benos - that error message can only be seen as the result of a PHP exception. We can't see what that exception is, only someone with access to the backend of the site and/or server logs can

Comment: I tried to understand how did you guys knew this is not a php error native to Drupal? I guess you have seen it in other PHP installments?... Ben.

Comment: @benos: please verify my edited (enhanced?) version of your question, to make sure I did not introduce anything you didn't intend/want. Of course feel free to further enhance where appropriate. Hope it'll help to get this question reopened ...

Comment: No, it's a generic error page that Drupal outputs when PHP encounters an exception that it can't recover from. You need to find out what that exception is, so that you can identify the part(s) of code you need to fix. It can't be done from here, only by someone with access to your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Screenack suggested.

1. Navigate to /admin/config/development/logging
2. Set the radio to **None**
3. Select Save Configuration

Please note that I recommend keeping the errors on locally and trying to fix them.

Comment: Hello Albertski, Thanks deeply for you answer, but I really need a pure CSS solution this time. I've updated the question. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: If I remember correctly what could fix it is a JS manipulation on the css, but it seems the problem itself was coming from the server and fixing it there was best.